# Getting this exception in pubspec.yaml while adding icon for my app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, pubspec

The current Dart SDK version is 2.12.2.

```
Because audioplayers 0.18.3 depends on uuid ^3.0.1 which depends on crypto ^3.0.0, audioplayers 0.18.3 requires crypto ^3.0.0.
```

(1) So, because archive >=2.0.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on crypto ^2.0.0, audioplayers 0.18.3 is incompatible with archive >=2.0.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0.

```
Because image >=2.0.4 <2.1.14 depends on archive >=1.0.16 <3.0.0 and archive ^1.0.2 requires SDK version <2.0.0, image >=2.0.4 <2.1.14 requires archive ^2.0.0.
And because flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 depends on image ^2.1.1 and image >=2.1.14 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on archive ^2.0.0, flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 requires archive ^2.0.0.
And because audioplayers 0.18.3 is incompatible with archive >=2.0.0 <3.0.0-nullsafety.0 (1), audioplayers 0.18.3 is incompatible with flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0.
So, because touch_sensitive_alarm depends on both flutter_launcher_icons ^0.7.2+1 and audioplayers 0.18.3, version solving failed.
```

pub get failed (1;     So, because touch_sensitive_alarm depends on both flutter_launcher_icons ^0.7.2+1 and audioplayers 0.18.3, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you use current Dart SDK you must check all your packages if have `null-safety` and update that packages if oudated.

Hopefully this can help you